# How to open and close RPM DB without leaking memory?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, rpm

I am working on emulating `rpm -qa` using my own code that uses the [librpm library](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/rpm/api/4.16.1/). I am doing this as initial experimentation for a larger program that will analyze installed software for security purposes.

For now, I only open the RPM DB and close it without reading anything.

When I compare the output of valgrind for my code and against the valgrind output for `rpm -qa`, here are the results:

```
$ valgrind ./leaky 
==8201== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8201== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8201== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8201== Command: ./leaky
==8201== 
==8201== 
==8201== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8201==     in use at exit: 104,700 bytes in 2,352 blocks
==8201==   total heap usage: 10,430 allocs, 8,078 frees, 2,292,650 bytes allocated
==8201== 
==8201== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8201==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8201==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8201==      possibly lost: 25,740 bytes in 325 blocks
==8201==    still reachable: 78,960 bytes in 2,027 blocks
==8201==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8201== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==8201== 
==8201== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==8201== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

```
$ valgrind rpm -qa > /dev/null
==8101== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8101== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8101== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8101== Command: rpm -qa
==8101== 
==8101== 
==8101== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8101==     in use at exit: 287 bytes in 2 blocks
==8101==   total heap usage: 170,103 allocs, 170,101 frees, 120,309,981 bytes allocated
==8101== 
==8101== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8101==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8101==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8101==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8101==    still reachable: 287 bytes in 2 blocks
==8101==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8101== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==8101== 
==8101== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==8101== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

As you can see, my program possibly lost 25,740 bytes, whereas `rpm -qa` lost 0 bytes.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <rpm/rpmdb.h>
#include <rpm/rpmlib.h>
#include <rpm/rpmts.h>

bool openDb(rpmts & ts, rpmdbMatchIterator & mi);
void closeDb(rpmts & ts, rpmdbMatchIterator & mi);

int main()
{
    rpmts ts;
    rpmdbMatchIterator mi;

    if (!openDb(ts, mi)) {
        return 1;
    }

    closeDb(ts, mi);
    return 0;
}

bool openDb(rpmts & ts, rpmdbMatchIterator & mi)
{
    {
        static volatile bool s_bHereBefore = false;
        if (!s_bHereBefore) {
            s_bHereBefore = true;
            rpmReadConfigFiles(NULL, NULL);
        }
    }

    mi = NULL;
    ts = rpmtsCreate();

    if (!ts) {
        printf("RPM open failed\n");
    } else {
        mi = rpmtsInitIterator(ts, (rpmTag)RPMDBI_PACKAGES, NULL, 0);
        if (!mi) {
            printf("RPM iterator failed\n");
            rpmtsFree(ts);
        }
    }

    return mi != NULL;
}

void closeDb(rpmts & ts, rpmdbMatchIterator & mi)
{
    mi = rpmdbFreeIterator(mi);
    if (ts) {
        rpmtsFree(ts);
    }
}
```

I compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wunused -Og -g try_to_fix_mem_leak.cpp -lrpm -o leaky`.

I closely inspected my program, but I was unable to spot any memory leaks from manual inspection.

When I run `valgrind --leak-check=full ./leaky` and search the output for `try_to_fix_mem_leak.cpp`, all of the hits are for line 27, i.e., the `rpmReadConfigFiles(NULL, NULL);` line (technically there are also hits for line 13, but that is just because that is where the `openDb` call is made in `main`). (See pastebin link below.) But I don't know how this line could cause any memory leaks. [The function's documentation for my version of librpm (4.16.1)](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/rpm/api/4.16.1/group__rpmrc.html#gaac91e0fc109eedd29b5aebed135b8580) doesn't mention anything about needing to free any memory.

How can I correctly open and close the RPM DB without leaking memory? Or, to put my question another way, how can I open and close the RPM DB while leaking at worst only as many bytes as `rpm -qa` does?

---

**Edit**

[pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/M2kQFTHZ) with full output of `valgrind --leak-check=full ./leaky`.

Comment: There are additional options you can pass to valgrind that will report exactly where the leaked memory was allocated and that should point you in the right direction. Check valgrind's documentation for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I tried using valgrind with `--leak-check=full`, but I don't see how the lines it is pointing to could be leaking. Please see my updated question, specifically the paragraph about `--leak-check=full` and `rpmReadConfigFiles`.

Comment: If you are only leaking memory at program exit, it most likely doesn't really matter - unless it means important destructors that do meaningful work, have not run. Once the executable exits, the kernel cleans up *all* it's memory (including what you've leaked). Actually; intentionally leaking memory can be a valid strategy to allow an application to shut down quickly, by avoiding unneeded object destruction and memory deallocation.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, the very last thing I do in my program after freeing the memory is exit (see the last two lines of my `main` function), so if there is any unfreed memory when my program exits, then to me that means I am leaking memory.

Comment: @ShaneBishop You can only leak memory while your program is running. Memory leaks are a problem because memory use continues to increase over time. Once your program exits, the kernel cleans up everything it ever allocated (even if you didn't). Memory leaks don't persist across multiple application launches/terminations.

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't fix your leaks. I'm just saying, that depending on their nature, they may be very low priority, possibly not even worth the effort, and in some applications you may see *intentional* at-exit leaks, and they are not necessarily bugs; just clever ways for some apps to shut down faster - not *all* leaks are bad.

Comment: "Possibly lost" is not a full-fledged memory leak. The usual reason are internal shared library static objects, and the shared library fails to clean it up when it gets unloaded. This is fairly common with C code. I do not see anything in the "updated question" that includes a backtrace that shows where the allegedly-leaking memory allocations come from. When I run valgrind I see complete backtraces, and in cases like these, if I have time to waste, I'll unwind the backtrace back to the code in the original C library, and verify this to be the case.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I wonder then whey valgrind finds no "possibly lost" bytes for `rpm -qa`, as the `rpm` binary uses the same librpm as I do (I confirmed this with `ldd` on both the `rpm` binary and my `leaky` binary). I would assume maybe the `rpm` binary does some global cleanup of static objects? If so, I would like to do the same cleanup in my code.

Comment: It's possible that the rpm library has some specific cleanup function that can be called to free it up. I would sift through the API documentation for something that indicates that. If not, I'll go pull up the source code, use the backtrace to find where the objects are located, look at the source, and grep around to see if there's something that clears it up.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, see [this pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/M2kQFTHZ) (also now linked in my question) to see the full `valgrind --leak-check=full` output with backtraces.

Comment: That's great, but what is your question? Stackoverflow is not a crowd-sourced debugging site, but a question/answer site.

Comment: My question is simply "How can I correctly open and close the RPM DB without leaking memory?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine found that, in the code for the `rpm` binary itself, the RPM devs [call the following two functions](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/blob/8a7a4e130578b11bf8087b503c53b8633478ed86/rpmbuild.c#L590-L591) to free their memory:

```cpp
rpmFreeMacros(NULL);
rpmFreeRpmrc();
```

To use `rpmFreeMacros()`, include the `rpm/rpmmacro.h` system header in your source code, and link against `librpmio.so`.

Here is my updated code:

```cpp
#include <rpm/rpmdb.h>
#include <rpm/rpmlib.h>
#include <rpm/rpmts.h>
#include <rpm/rpmmacro.h>

bool openDb(rpmts & ts, rpmdbMatchIterator & mi);
void closeDb(rpmts & ts, rpmdbMatchIterator & mi);

int main()
{
    rpmts ts;
    rpmdbMatchIterator mi;

    if (!openDb(ts, mi)) {
        return 1;
    }

    closeDb(ts, mi);
    return 0;
}

bool openDb(rpmts & ts, rpmdbMatchIterator & mi)
{
    {
        static volatile bool s_bHereBefore = false;
        if (!s_bHereBefore) {
            s_bHereBefore = true;
            rpmReadConfigFiles(NULL, NULL);
        }
    }

    mi = NULL;
    ts = rpmtsCreate();

    if (!ts) {
        printf("RPM open failed\n");
    } else {
        mi = rpmtsInitIterator(ts, (rpmTag)RPMDBI_PACKAGES, NULL, 0);
        if (!mi) {
            printf("RPM iterator failed\n");
            rpmtsFree(ts);
        }
    }

    return mi != NULL;
}

void closeDb(rpmts & ts, rpmdbMatchIterator & mi)
{
    mi = rpmdbFreeIterator(mi);
    if (ts) {
        rpmtsFree(ts);
    }
    rpmFreeMacros(NULL);
    rpmFreeRpmrc();
}
```

Here is a diff between my new code (`leak_fixed.cpp`) and my old leaky code (`try_to_fix_mem_leak.cpp`):

```
$ diff -u try_to_fix_mem_leak.cpp leak_fixed.cpp 
--- try_to_fix_mem_leak.cpp 2023-01-04 10:19:28.084587731 -0500
+++ leak_fixed.cpp  2023-01-04 10:19:57.484483431 -0500
@@ -1,6 +1,7 @@
 #include <rpm/rpmdb.h>
 #include <rpm/rpmlib.h>
 #include <rpm/rpmts.h>
+#include <rpm/rpmmacro.h>
 
 bool openDb(rpmts & ts, rpmdbMatchIterator & mi);
 void closeDb(rpmts & ts, rpmdbMatchIterator & mi);
@@ -50,4 +51,6 @@
     if (ts) {
         rpmtsFree(ts);
     }
+    rpmFreeMacros(NULL);
+    rpmFreeRpmrc();
 }
```

I compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wunused -Og -g leak_fixed.cpp -lrpm -lrpmio -o rpm_open_close`. Note that I needed to add `-lrpmio` in order to be able to use the `rpmFreeMacros()` function.

I get the same leak summary output from valgrind for both my binary and for the system `rpm` binary:

```
$ valgrind ./rpm_open_close 
==3470== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3470== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3470== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3470== Command: ./rpm_open_close
==3470== 
==3470== 
==3470== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3470==     in use at exit: 287 bytes in 2 blocks
==3470==   total heap usage: 10,495 allocs, 10,493 frees, 2,317,132 bytes allocated
==3470== 
==3470== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3470==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3470==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3470==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3470==    still reachable: 287 bytes in 2 blocks
==3470==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3470== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3470== 
==3470== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==3470== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

```
$ valgrind rpm -qa > /dev/null
==3483== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3483== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3483== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3483== Command: rpm -qa
==3483== 
==3483== 
==3483== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3483==     in use at exit: 287 bytes in 2 blocks
==3483==   total heap usage: 172,604 allocs, 172,602 frees, 121,827,169 bytes allocated
==3483== 
==3483== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3483==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3483==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3483==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3483==    still reachable: 287 bytes in 2 blocks
==3483==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3483== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3483== 
==3483== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==3483== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```